# JupyterNotebook InvalidArgumentError: b'No files matched pattern: Expected 'tf.Tensor(False, shape=(), dtype=bool)' to be true

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

for a Face ID project, I've succesfully created some folder structures, made directories, collected some positive and anchor classes through the webcam, (for the negative class, I'v used LFW dataset) but when I try to get image directories through this code, I get an error:

```
anchor = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(ANC_PATH+'\*.jpg').take(300)
positive = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(POS_PATH+'\.jpg').take(300)
negative = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(NEG_PATH+'\.jpg').take(300)
```

> InvalidArgumentError: Expected 'tf.Tensor(False, shape=(),
> dtype=bool)' to be true. Summarized data: b'No files matched pattern:
> data\positive\.jpg'

This image shows the full error I got:
[image]

Comment: it seems to me you forgot stars here `\.jpg` -> `\*.jpg`

Comment: wow. I didn't even notice that. I probably need a break... haha.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this. Just change the ' \ ' to '/'.

```
anchor = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(ANC_PATH+'/*.jpg').take(300)
```